# Arithmetic operators with SELECT, LEFT JOIN and WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, join

I need help. I have the code below which works fine but its not achieving my objective. I want a column "account_title" with each of its calculated values by the side before the subtraction which should eventually give me the difference of the subtracted value. Thanks in anticipation.

```
SELECT
(
    SELECT SUM(amount)
    FROM mainaccount_a_2017
    LEFT JOIN chart_of_account ON (chart_of_account.joint_account_numbers = mainaccount_a_2017.joint_account_number)
    LEFT JOIN asset_liability_income_expenditure_tbl ON (asset_liability_income_expenditure_tbl.a_l_code = chart_of_account.account_type)
    WHERE a_l_code = 'FA' AND dr_cr_action = 'DR'
)
-
(
    SELECT SUM(amount)
    FROM mainaccount_b_2017
    LEFT JOIN chart_of_account ON (chart_of_account.joint_account_numbers = mainaccount_b_2017.joint_account_number)
    LEFT JOIN asset_liability_income_expenditure_tbl ON (asset_liability_income_expenditure_tbl.a_l_code = chart_of_account.account_type)
    WHERE a_l_code = 'FA' AND dr_cr_action = 'CR'
)
```

Comment: WHY ARE YOU SHOUTING AT US? It is not appropriate here to type your question in ALL CAPS. It makes text harder to read, it's rude, and it will not get you help faster. Look at the main page's list of questions - how many do you see in ALL CAPS besides yours? The answer: None, because it's not proper to do so. Please stop.

Comment: Where does the account title come from? You're not grouping the queries by account.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Barmar the `Group By` was helpful, but the actual values is still not aligned as expected.

Comment: Apologies @Ken ...Noted..Just new here, but trust me, am learning fast, Ok. Thanks.

Comment: You still haven't answered my question. Your queries are calculating totals for all accounts, how is it supposed to display an account title?

Comment: @Barmar account_title is the column that hold the description for the amount in question. For example, **School Fee** (data held in account_title), **amount** (1500). I don't know if its clear enough?

Comment: Not clear enough. Which table does that come from?

Comment: @Barmar **Same Table** like `mainaccount_a_2017.account_title` or `mainaccount_b_2017.account_title` depending as the case may be.

Comment: Thanks. :-) Also, instead of forcing us to play 20 questions with you to get details, it would be extremely helpful if you provided sample data and the output you're trying to obtain from that data along with your question.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks for that. I have Sample Data and Screen Shot here [https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B4uzIxyf_WfVVXFoSFk4NnJXS1U?usp=sharing]

Comment: @KenWhite here is another perspective to the question asked [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4uzIxyf_WfVOEp1N0RCY1dlX1k)

Comment: We don't go off-site to get details needed to understand the question. All relevant information needs to be here, in the question itself. If important details are off-site, and  the off-site location is unavailable (off-line, moved, deleted, etc.), the question loses all value to future users of the site and therefore doesn't belong here. You should spend some time taking the [tour] and reading through the [help] pages.

Answer (score 0):

Change the subqueries to be grouped by `account_title`, and then join them.

```
SELECT debits.account_title, debits.total - credits.total AS net_reduction
FROM (
    SELECT mainaccount_a_2017.account_title, SUM(amount) AS total
    FROM mainaccount_a_2017
    LEFT JOIN chart_of_account ON (chart_of_account.joint_account_numbers = mainaccount_a_2017.joint_account_number)
    LEFT JOIN asset_liability_income_expenditure_tbl ON (asset_liability_income_expenditure_tbl.a_l_code = chart_of_account.account_type)
    WHERE a_l_code = 'FA' AND dr_cr_action = 'DR'
    GROUP BY mainaccount_a_2017.account_title
) AS debits
JOIN (
    SELECT mainaccount_b_2017.account_title, SUM(amount) AS total
    FROM mainaccount_b_2017
    LEFT JOIN chart_of_account ON (chart_of_account.joint_account_numbers = mainaccount_b_2017.joint_account_number)
    LEFT JOIN asset_liability_income_expenditure_tbl ON (asset_liability_income_expenditure_tbl.a_l_code = chart_of_account.account_type)
    WHERE a_l_code = 'FA' AND dr_cr_action = 'CR'
    GROUP BY mainaccount_b_2017.account_title
) AS credits ON debits.account_title = credits.account_title
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1309b0/1)

Comment: Thanks for that, but I got this error message about ambiguity `#1052 - Column 'account_title' in field list is ambiguous`. I have concatenated the account_title and flipped somethings over. I think, what you did is very close, I can feel it, but am not yet there...

Comment: That means you have `account_title` in other tables, so you need the table prefix. I've updated the answer to show this.

Comment: If you have the account title in other tables, that's bad normalization. It should only be in the account list.

Comment: @Barmar conditional aggregation would avoid code duplication.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I thought so too, but they're different tables. `_a_` and `_b_`.

Comment: Ah.. I've lost the "Find the difference" game :-)

Comment: @Barmar this is a link for the sample data and a screenshot for a better perspective [https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B4uzIxyf_WfVVXFoSFk4NnJXS1U?usp=sharing]]. Thanks

Comment: Put the relevant parts of that into the question.

Comment: @Barmar `#1054 - Unknown column 'credits.total' in 'field list'`

Comment: Obviously that's because I forgot `AS total` in the second subquery. Fixed.

Comment: @Barmar. Thanks alot. Its doing all I expected. But, how can I get the `account_title` to list with the respective values before the arithmetic? I just have only one item in the `account_title` and it ought to be a list.

Comment: I don't understand. Edit the question, showing the input data and the desired result.

Comment: What do you mean you only have one item? I see `NUC GRANTS`, `POST GRADUATE EXAMINATION FEES`, `OTHER GRANTS AND GIFTS`, and `ADMIN. AND GENERAL EXPENSES`.

Comment: @Barmar I have printed screenshots here (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4uzIxyf_WfVd2FfZ1VIRkpjUmM) and (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4uzIxyf_WfVM05nN0hIak5rVFU) **have a look!**

Comment: @Barmar here is another perspective to the question asked [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4uzIxyf_WfVOEp1N0RCY1dlX1k)

Comment: Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15315779) edit suggestion on your answer. It should have been addressed to you

Comment: @Barmar you're the BEST. Thanks Honey for the link, didn't notice. Am grateful.

Comment: @AderogbaOtunla You should edit the question, not my answer.

Comment: I've created a demo on sqlfiddle, it gets the correct answer per your screenshot. So I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: @Barmar read up! Already said you're the best. Didn't know when you updated the code. But its good so far. Thanks Once again! **It worked**